# mysql select query with where condition in a range of records

Tags: mysql, limit

I want to select only those records from a specific range of 10 records where a condition satisfy. That range can be 0-10 or 20-30 or 35-45 or any range.

```
select Cid, Company_Name, completed from table1;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Cid   | Company_Name                                       | completed |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 73855 | company 1                                          |         1 |
| 73894 | company 2                                          |         2 |
| 73906 | company 3                                          |         2 |
| 73909 | company 4                                          |         2 |
| 73921 | company 5                                          |         1 |
| 73924 | company 6                                          |         1 |
| 73936 | company 7                                          |         2 |
| 73939 | company 8                                          |         2 |
| 73955 | company 9                                          |         2 |
| 73994 | company 10                                         |         2 |
| 74003 | company 11                                         |         0 |
```

Now i want to fetch only those records between row number 10-20 in table which have `completed=2`.

I tried something like:

`select Cid, Company_Name, completed from table1 t1 where completed=2 in (select Cid, Company_Name, completed from table1 t2 limit 10,10);`

But this gives me error:

`ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

using the limit like this:

`select Cid, Company_Name from table1 t1 where completed=2 limit 10,10;`

apply where condition first then apply limit of selected result. I want to apply limit first then apply the where condition.

Comment: @gkol Through mysql there is no way to first fetch a records from a specific range of rows from table then apply a condition to filter down the rows?

Comment: thanks @Strawberry, this is about mysql and I edit my statement. I'm also trying to help our friend now. progressing ....

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: (It seems to work well on the version I tested, which is mySQL 5.6):

```
select * from (
select * from table1 limit 10, 10) t1 where t1.completed = 2
```

Comment: i got this error `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias`. my Mysql version `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for osx10.6 (i386) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: @MutantMahesh Maybe you made a mistake when transcribing Greg's solution. And note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql we can limit by adding "Offset" before "where":

```
select Cid, Company_Name from table1 t1 limit 10 offset 0 where completed=2
```

UPDATED:
Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: No we can't. Suggest queries are tested before posting.

Comment: oh I see, I would test it then, has @MutantMahesh already tested it too?

Comment: No, syntax 'where completed=2' Error in Version. By the way, what version is being used ? give up, that's what I know